# Flows metadata that Bypass User Permissions (SFDX)

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, salesforcedx-cli, visual-flows, summer20

In Summer 20, we have a possibility of define a "Run mode" of a Visual Flow, to run avoiding user permission, as we can see on this link: [Run Flows That Bypass User Permissions](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_system_mode_no_sharing.htm).

But when you create a flow, with "System Context Without Sharing-Access All Data" option on "How to run flow" field and pulled it from Scratch org to your local branch, you receive a flow metadata (xml) without any reference to this "Run mode". In related link ([Tooling API New and Changed Objects](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_api_tooling_new_and_changed_objects.htm)
), they refer to a runInMode field and SystemModeWithoutSharing (enum) option to set you flow without user permission... but it isn't on metadata. Look at this flow metadata example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <interviewLabel>test {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}</interviewLabel>
    <label>test</label>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>BuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>OriginBuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processType>Flow</processType>
    <screens>
        <name>test</name>
        <label>test</label>
        <locationX>430</locationX>
        <locationY>70</locationY>
        <allowBack>true</allowBack>
        <allowFinish>true</allowFinish>
        <allowPause>true</allowPause>
        <showFooter>true</showFooter>
        <showHeader>true</showHeader>
    </screens>
    <start>
        <locationX>50</locationX>
        <locationY>50</locationY>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>test</targetReference>
        </connector>
    </start>
    <status>Active</status>
</Flow>
```

Any ideas how to add this "RunInMode" and "SystemModeWithoutSharing" on flow metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this and it works without any issues.

Here are couple of steps I recommend you double check,

1. Make sure you are on latest version of SFDX CLI by running `sfdx update`
2. Make sure the apiVersion is specified as 49.0

In your `sfdx-project.json` make sure it is 49.0

```
    "sourceApiVersion": "49.0",
```

Comment: Yes! I justed updated SFDX CLI, but the version was 47.0. Now I changed to 49.0 and works fine! Thanks a lot!